Undertow pending blocking requests when loading static resources
For a Spring Boot, Spring Cloud Gateway and Spring Webflux application with an Angular front-end.
When the application is packaged, the front-end .js bundles and other resources are copied to the /target/classes/static directory.
Once the application is deployed, serving some resources may randomly block. The requests to grab them stay pending. When refreshing the page, it may work or block on another resource.
Besides this:
Refresh (f5) and force refresh (ctrl+f5) have the same outcome. Compression is enabled with the server.compression properties. Issue arise in multiple web browsers (Chrome, Edge, FF). No errors are logged back or front-end side.
Since resources are sometimes served properly we can say
. Static resource auto discovery by the Spring Boot container works.
. Resources are not blocked by security filters.
The application is deployed on the embedded Undertow server that Spring Boot provides. Switching to an embedded Tomcat fixes the issue.
Could anyone help me figure why Undertow would behave like this ?
